# Join dataset to geography in Carto (Python)

Tags: python, carto, pandas

I'm subscribed to two datasets and one geography on Carto Data Observatory. How can I join them to each other using Python?

I have converted both datasets and geography into pandas dataframe, then I used the `DataFrame.merge` function but I am still unable to do the join.

Datasets and Geographies are related to each other by geoid field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carto gave me this solution:

```
BBOX = 'x,y,x,y'
bq_client = BigQueryClient(None)

query = '''
SELECT agg(a.column1) as column1, agg(a.columns2) as columnn2, b.column1, st_astext(b.geom) as geom
 FROM `carto-do-customers.user_name.dataset_name` a

 INNER JOIN `carto-do-customers.user-name.dataset_name` b ON a.geoid=b.id

 WHERE ST_IntersectsBox(b.geom,{BBOX})

 GROUP BY b.geoid, geom
'''.format(BBOX=BBOX)

dataframe = bq_client.query(query).to_dataframe()
```

It worked for me, I hope it works for you, guys!

Comment: You forgot to mention you were using BigQuery. Next time please do not omit important information.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I promise not to omit something like that in the future. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

If `df1` is the dataframe with geometry, you can do something like this:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='geoid', how='left')
```

If you are using CARTO, another solution could be using `JOIN`s as explained [here](https://carto.com/help/tutorials/relational-joins-and-spatial-joins/).